# can we make one cell appear at end of screen irrespective of contents in UITableView iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make one cell appear at end of screen all the time irrespective of contents in UITableView iOS swift

Comment: Do you mean, like a footer?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I have already tried it. FooterView appears at the end of the last cell of tableView. In my case the cells are less, in the smaller device the whole screen should be scrollable and In the device, with larger height, the last cell's content should be attached at the bottom of the screen. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add table footer view

Using StoryBoard

In TableView You can drag UIView, it will set as FooterView if you have more then 0 prototype cell. After Drag you can see it in tableview hierarchy as subview.

Programmatically

Follow 3 Steps

Make one custom view as footer view,
Swift 3.X / Swift 4.X

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
```

Swift 2.X

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
```

Add that view in Table Footer View.
Swift 2.X/Swift 3.X/Swift 4.X

```
myTblView.tableFooterView = customView
```

If it is not work then please try to add table view section footer
Sample Program-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sampleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    sampleView.frame = CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 5, 60, 4);
    sampleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return sampleView;
}
```

and include UITableViewDelegate protocol.

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this solution does not hold good. I have already tried it.  FooterView appears at the end of the last cell of tableView. But In my case the cells are less, in the smaller device the whole screen should be scrollable and In the device, with larger height, the last cell's content should be attached at the bottom of the screen. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Try to add tableview section footer, updated sample code in the answer